# I have got "403 Forbidden" using custom search engine on payed account

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use google search engine via python script. It was working fine at the beginning but later I have got "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden". I thing it is due to 100 requests per day limitation. But I have payed account and billing support told me that everyting is ok. Is it possible somehow to solve this problesm?
Thanks, Ilia

Comment: Hi Ilia, and welcome to Stackoverflow. It looks like you need to improve your question and give more details, to get an answer. Please have look at these guidelines when you are posting a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- You are more likely to get an answer if your follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of reasons for which API will throw Error 403. You can find them all here : [GOOGLE DOC FOR 403 Forbidden](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#403forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

Your 403 error might indicate that the API key you are using may have lost it's permissions, or that the quota of your API requests may have been exceeded and the new quota (The one you have when you already have a billing account) might not have been updated.

I assume you are using this [API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?hl=en_US); If not, don't worry, the following advice might also help you.

You first need to see if your API key is still working or you might want to generate new ones. You can do this [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?hl=en_US#api_key). Your code should make reference to the new API Key file.

If it is not the case then you should wait a little bit until your Billing account is updated and the quota gets readjusted. You can read a bit more about how to monitor the requests to your APIs [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota).

You can always find more help with your particular issue if you describe a little  the symptoms and your attempts or hypothesis to solve it.

At last you may find more info on the [community page](https://support.google.com/customsearch/community) of the API.